# What free CMS can do the following

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I'm looking for a CMS I can embed inside an already existing php website. Basically I just want something that I can make blog posts from and then those blog posts will show up inside my                                                                                                           website's content `div`. I'm really not looking for anything too fancy but don't really want to hack wordpress. Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Wordpress isn't that bad an idea for this: You can access WordPress content from within a PHP application on the same server by including the WordPress bootstrap. You can then list and/or fetch the blog entry / article / page you need.

See e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829199/include-wordpress-content-outside-of-wordpress) and especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827238/incorporate-wordpress-into-kohana-3) (Galen's top voted answer shows the whole process of fetching a page.)

Comment: I was going to post that link!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Osmek's free account.  Osmek integrates easily into an existing application since its centrally hosted and requires no database setup.  Check out this video http://osmek.com/video

Disclaimer I work for Osmek, so I am biased.  But feel free to ask me any question.

Answer (score 0):

[Joomla](http://joomla.org) makes it about as simple as possible and will leave room for the day a client calls up and asks for a more advanced feature. Installation into a folder is something pretty common, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are [multiple](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+embeddable+cms) options which are prepositioned for embedding. Most promising seems "PHP News System" http://phpns.alecwh.com/, though I haven't used it and cannot qualify it much. But it claims the embedding process is just a single php call, which still sounds acceptable.

If you want just a blog, I'd recommend [Serendipity](http://www.s9y.org/) over Wordpress. Firstly because of the better security track record, and second because it specifically has a switch for embedding it within an existing layout; so unlike WP doesn't need as much workarounds.